# Convert milliseconds to formatted date in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I'm sure this should be simple (probably missing something obvious), but... I have a database string of milliseconds I want to convert into a US-formatted date in Rails. Figured calling `.to_date` would be my friend, but it's throwing a strange error.

```
article.date => "1379844601000"

article.date.to_date
NoMethodError: undefined method `div' for nil:NilClass
```

Can anyone advise the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `Date.strptime`- but before this, convert it to seconds first:

```
sec = ('1379844601000'.to_f / 1000).to_s
Date.strptime(sec, '%s')
//Sun, 22 Sep 2013
```

Comment: This works great, thanks - is there any way to display it as MM-DD-YYYY instead of DAY, DD MMM YYYY?

Answer (score 65):

Convert it to seconds `(milliseconds/1000)` and call `Time::at` on the result:

```
Time.at(1379844601000/1000)
# => 2013-09-22 12:10:01 +0200
```

[Time::at on ruby-doc.org](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Time.html#method-c-at)

Comment: But better to use float 1000.0 if want to include milliseconds part in result.

Answer (score 54):

```
Time.strptime(milliseconds.to_s, '%Q')
// %Q - Number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
```

Comment: @zenbro Why `Time.strptime(sec, '%Q')` return 1 day difference with `Date.strptime(sec, '%s')` ?

Answer (score -1):

Time.parse("1379844601000") will give you the date and time

Comment: Is that working for you? It gives me `ArgumentError: no time information in "1379844601000"`. Date.parse gives `ArgumentError: invalid date`.

Comment: It is working fine for me
>> Time.parse("1379844601000")
=> Sun Sep 22 16:32:36 +0530 2013

Comment: Looks like its a ruby version problem. Ruby 1.9.x versions don't have this parse option. So, you can use Time.strptime() method or use some gems like this https://github.com/jeremyevans/ruby-american_date